# Why is newline character in command line argument unescaped?

Tags: windows, .net-core, command-line

I created a .NET 6 console app with Visual Studio 2022 and set the command line arguments to:

```
Thisisa\newtest
```

When I launch the app, the `\n` in the string is replaced with a newline character.  I don't recall ever observing this behavior before.  I knew the command line can unescape sequences like `\"`, but I've never heard of it happening for `\n`.

Why is newline character in an argument passed to Windows console application unescaped?

**UPDATE**:

Here is the code:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World! - " + args[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the debug profile:

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "ConsoleApp": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "commandLineArgs": "Thisisa\\newtest"
    }
  }
}
```

I am using Visual Studio 2022, version 17.2.6.  When the app is run the following is output:

[image: Console window]

Comment: "set the command line arguments to" where? In VS?

Comment: Yes, in VS.  Or, just launch the app from the command line and enter the arguments there.  The result is the same.

Comment: Never heard of that. Would be some regression to existing behavior. Also, I cannot reproduce this. Used `args[]`, `Environment.GetCommandLine()` and `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`. Tried in PowerShell and CMD (just for sanities sake) and all the time the `\n` remains literally a backslash and the character n. You might want to show your project file, actual code and specify exactly which shell/environment you are using.

Answer (score 0):

this helped me:

```
args[0].Replace("\n", "\\n");
```